# MySQL doesn't let me delete record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this MySQL clause from PHP

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE id in (select DISTINCT(id) FROM table_2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE p = 1 AND r =1))";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

I get the following error

> Error deleting record: You can't specify target table 'table_2' for
>   update in FROM clause

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass this limitation of MySQL with a subquery, but your statement can be simplified like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_2 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE p = 1 AND r = 1
  ) t
)
```

Comment: then I get this. Error deleting record: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Did you forget the alias `t`?

Comment: oh lol, i thought it was a typo, now i get this error: Error deleting record: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:'Question1'

Comment: This is not an error from the delete statement itself. Maybe you have constraints or triggers that cause other deletes or updates.

Comment: that's the only delete/update i have in that whole php file, other updates i guess are the inserts but they're in another file

Comment: Yes, but for this table maybe there are defined triggers or other constraints.

Comment: okay it worked like this `DELETE FROM table_2 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE p = '1' AND r = '1'
  ) t
) `

Comment: This means that p and r are strings and not numbers, right?

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you may consider accepting it.

Comment: yeah it was a string, i will accept it once i figure out how lol

Comment: nvm just did it